# woocommerce api create order set line item price

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to create order via woocommerce API V3. The problems I cannot add the line_item with a custom price. Is it possible?

```
line_items:[ {
    product_id: 9344, 
    quantity: 1,
    subtotal: 10,
    total: 10 
  }]
```

Currently I get this error:

```
    code: 'rest_invalid_param',
    message: 'Invalid parameter(s): line_items',
```

Comment: Please check this out - https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-an-order

Comment: Mention the API version as well

Comment: I did read the doc. It did not say whether the line_item can change the item price.

Comment: See the order properties - some are readonly https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#order-line-items-properties

Comment: For total it did not say it’s read only

Comment: You need to send the subtotal, total, subtotal_tax, and total_tax also if changing cost

Comment: OK - Let me know how it went

Comment: No, it does not work. According to the doc subtotal_tax, and total_tax are read only

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. There needs to be double quotes around the total value.

```
line_items:[ {
    product_id: 9344, 
    total: "10"
  }]
```